# Hot to update dynamically font size

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this css file which sets the default font size and type in JavaFX application:

```
.root {
  -fx-font: 13px Tahoma;
}

scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles/Styles.css").toExternalForm());
```

I want to update the size and the font type from the Java code dynamically of the root component (all components). How I can do this?

Note:
This code updates the Font type and size of all components into the JavaFX application.

Comment: You have a contradiction in a question. Please revise it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider taking a look at the official JavaFX [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/text/jfxpub-text.htm). There you find the code example which answers your question:

```
Text t = new Text("That's the text");
t.setFont(Font.font ("Verdana", 20));
```

**UPDATE**

In your application controller get an instance of your root pane, e.g. `AnchorPane` and use the `setId("")` function to set new style for the whole pane (my `actionChange` is connected with a button on the pane, which triggers the event/change):

```
public class AppController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane mainPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @FXML
    public void actionChange() {
        mainPane.setId("fancytext");
    }
}
```

When pressing the button, the style for the pane is changed. I just used the font-size as an example. Before, you need to specify the new style in your CSS file:

```
.root {
    -fx-font: 12px Tahoma;
}

#fancytext {
    -fx-font: 20px Tahoma;
}
```

That's before:

[image: Before the button is pressed]

That's after the button was pressed:

[image: After the button is pressed]